# What is "Representation State" in REST archtecture

Tags: rest, web, asp.net-web-api, resources

I'm trying to understand the principles of REST architecture, but I'm struggle to understand what the Representational State is and how it is transferred.

Also, [here](https://www.servage.net/blog/2013/04/08/rest-principles-explained/), I encountered the concept "representation of a resource". What is the meaning of "representation of a resource"? This abstraction confuses me...

From Roy Fielding's Ph.D. dissertation:

> “Representational State Transfer is intended to evoke an image of how
>   a well-designed Web application behaves: a network of web pages (a
>   virtual state-machine), where the user progresses through an
>   application by selecting links (state transitions), resulting in the
>   next page (representing the next state of the application) being
>   transferred to the user and rendered for their use.”

Maybe, a simple example will help to understand the abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this tutorial

[Learn REST: A RESTful Tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html)

They break down the meanings of the abstractions, which should clear up any confusions you may be having in understanding.

Basically the resource represents a thing. There can be different representations of a resource. Think of it like different shapes of an item or thing.

Representations:

- How resources get manipulated
- Part of the resource state

  - Transferred between client and server
- Typically JSON or XML
- Example:

  - Resource: person (Todd)
  - Service: contact information (GET)
  - Representation:

    - name, address, phone number
    - JSON or XML format

The video really tries to explain  the topic in a way that is very understandable. They explain the Roy Fielding doctoral dissertation found at

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm